# how to avoid overwriting sqlSessionFactory

Tags: spring, mybatis

I have a web app which imports 2 jars.

Both jars use MyBatis and Spring

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:persistence/ormConfig-content-repository.xml" />  
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:persistence/content-repository-mapper/*.xml" /> 
</bean>
```

In both cases I am using the SqlSessionDaoSupport which uses the sqlSessionFactory

The problem arises when I deploy the app

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<description>Spring config file</description>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    classpath:jar1_conf.xml,
    classpath:jar2_conf.xml
</param-value>
```

basically the sqlSessionFactory bean defined in the second jar overwrites the one defined in the first jar.

What can I do?
please help

Comment: Anyone has any ideas please

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer that won't help you is that is Spring's behavior.  You're basically creating one ApplicationContext and loading two beans with the same name so one will overwrite the other.  The solution would be to create more than one ApplicationContext for your app.